# How to control the number of digits when performing element-wise division of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r

When performing element-wise division of vectors in R-studio, the numbers in the result are rounded and show too few digits for my purpose. How can I control the number of digits visible?

I looked on the web for solutions via functions like 'format' or options(digits=...) but none of them allow me to see more digits after the decimal in the console or the global environment.

I have the following 2 vectors defined in R studio:

```
distance <- c(0.8, 3.1, 2.8, 4.0) #miles

time <- c(10, 30, 40, 50) #minutes

time<-time/60
```

However, when dividing both to get the speed, the numbers shown are rounded:

`speed<-distance/time`

For instance, the 4th element speed[4] shows `4.8` in my console in R studio and global environment while it is actually `4.801920768`.

I hope somebody can help?

Thank you!
Abigail

Comment: The 4th value should be exactly 4.8:  it's `4/(50/60)`, i.e. `24/5`.

Comment: Try `format(4.0/0.8333333, nsmall = 9)`. It coerces the result to a character though. If you must, see `?format` for more info.

Comment: You can use `print(speed, digits= 22)`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @user2554330: oops, yes, you are right...apparently I typed too few digits myself when doing the 'manual' calculation, thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @schwantke: thank you, it works now with this line!

Comment: @deepseefan: thanks, this indeed also does the trick!